# Seleccionar una opción de una tabla en Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, formularios, cpanel

**Tengo un sitio donde el admin accede y crea sedes. Cuando crea una sede debe poner nombre, localidad y provincia.** Los datos de las sedes se guardan en una tabla llamada w_sedes.

Logre que todos los datos se suban a la base de datos (a la tabla w_sedes) y que una tabla muestre la lista de sedes (una lista que muestra todos los datos de la tabla w_sedes)

Pero **quiero que al crear la sede, seleccione de un dropdown la pronvincia** (Hay una tabla ya creada que tiene todas las provincias. Se llama w_provincias)

Cómo hago que seleccione una opción de una tabla y que se guarde la opción?

Un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer: Cuando creas una cuenta en un sitio y seleccionas tu país de un dropdown.

**Esto muestra la lista de sedes creadas:**

```
    <table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="1" align="center" style="line-height:25px;">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Localidad</th>
<th>Provincia</th>

</tr>
<?php
//Fetch Data form database
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['idxSedeV']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['localidad']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['idxProv']; ?></td>


        <!--Edit option -->
        <td><a href="editsede.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['idxSedeV']; ?>" alt="edit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Editar</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">No se encontro ninguna data!</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>

</table>

<br>
<div align="center">
<a href="nuevasede.html" class='btn btn-outline-primary'>Nuevo</a>
</div>

</table>
```

**Este es el formulario para crear una sede:**

```
<form method="post" action="crearsede.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">        
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre y apellido" required>      
  </div>

      <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidad" placeholder="Ingrese localidad" required>      
      </div>

<div class="form-group">        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="provincia" placeholder="Ingrese provincia" required>  
   </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Finalizar</button>
    </form>   
<hr />
<a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='listasedes.php' role='button'>Cancelar</a>

    </td></tr>
</table>
```

**Intente esto pero no funciono:**

```
<select name="provincia" id="provincia" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="">Seleccione una opcion</option>
       <script type="text/javascript">

        <?php
      $conn = mysqli_connect("sitio.com", "test", "test", "test");
      mysql_select_db("provincia",$conn);
      mysql_set_charset("utf8",$con);
      $consulta1= mysql_query("SELECT w_provincias as x FROM nombre "); 
          while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta1)){
                     $nombre=$data['x'];
                     echo "<option value='".$nombre."' $selected>".$nombre."</option>"; 
                    }
         ?>
         </script>
    </select>
```

Comment: OJO, tienes dos veces el método en tu formulario: `<form method="post" action="crearsede.php" method="POST">` En cuanto a tu pregunta, tienes que recoger el dato usando la superglobal `$_POST`, dado que el select se llama `provincia`, tienes que recoger el dato así: `$_POST["provincia"]` te recomendaria que guardes el ID de la provincia y no el nombre, y más adelante puedes hacer `JOIN` de ambas tablas si quisieras mostrar el nombre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude resolverlo así: (hice una pag en blanco para probar)

```
<?php
//Connection for database
$conn = mysqli_connect("sitio.com", "test", "test", "test");
//Select Database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>


<select id="select-provincia">
  <option disabled selected>Seleccione provincia</option>
  <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['idxProv'] ?>"><?php echo $row['provincia'] ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

También corregí lo de `<form method="post" action="crearsede.php" method="POST">` .
Gracias por la ayuda

Ahora el problema es que lo agrego pero no aparece:

```
<div align="center">
<table>

    <tr><td>

<!--Formulario de registro-->

    <h3>Nueva sede</h3><hr />

    <form method="post" action="crearsede.php">
      <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre y apellido" required>      
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localidad" placeholder="Ingrese localidad" required>      
      </div>

<div class="form-group">        


<select id="country-select">
  <option disabled selected>Seleccione provincia</option>

  <?php

//Connection for database
$conn = mysqli_connect("sitio.com", "test", "test", "test");
//Select Database
$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM w_provincias";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  ?>


  <option value="<?php echo $row['idxProv'] ?>"><?php echo $row['provincia'] ?></option>

</select>




    </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Finalizar</button>
    </form>   

<!--END Formulario de registro-->
<hr />
<a class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='listasedes.php' role='button'>Cancelar</a>

    </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

te dejo un ejemplo que utilice yo en un caso similar

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" style="width:40%" class="form-control pull-left">

                                    <option disabled selected value ></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $clavebuscadah = mysql_query("select * from equipo", $link) or
                                            die("Problemas en el select:" . mysql_error());
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($clavebuscadah)) {
                                        echo'<OPTION VALUE="' . $row['equi_nombre'] . '">' . $row['equi_nombre'] . ' </OPTION>';
                                        //$categoria = $row['cate_nomb'];
                                    }
                                    ?>

                                </select>
```